# NDA and Applying for Unemployment

Tags: california, non-disclosure, unemployment

Is information required for an Unemployment application exempt from NDAs? I signed one when I was hired, agreeing not to discuss my employer (a celebrity, hence the NDA), employment, separation, etc. but does that mean I can't explain the circumstances of my firing to the Unemployment office? I wasn't fired for something that should prevent me from receiving Unemployment, and the circumstances of my firing don't reflect negatively on the celebrity or the company.

Answer (score 1):

Google for free/low cost legal help in your county in California and get a lawyer to read the NDA and advise you on what you can/can't say. There could be an exception already in the NDA. See [California Bar - Free Legal Help](http://www.calbar.ca.gov/Public/Need-Legal-Help/Free-Legal-Help). If not, they may need to contact the legal representatives of your past employer to amend the NDA so you can give the unemployment office what they need to know.